# How to check 2checkout system without real credit card?

Tags: 2checkout

Is it possible to check the 2checkout system without real credit card numbers?
Do fake numbers exist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using 2checkout [sanbox](https://sandbox.2checkout.com/sandbox), test datas are provided in below link:

https://www.2checkout.com/documentation/sandbox/test-data